# Continious running Azure Webjob goes to sleep

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

We have a WebJob in our Azure website that was supposed to listen to some messages on Azure Service Bus (ASB), so based on that we were expecting to run a process continuously so that it can listen to bus messages and process them as soon as they arrive. so with this background we chose “Run continuously” as WebJobs’s schedule at deployment time.

After some time, it appears that the WebJob does not work! and as usual we checked the Azure portal in that environment and checked the status of the job and noticed that it is running!

But the observation was, as soon as we open the WebJob tab in the azure portal we could see that it says “Web Job Starting” and after a few seconds it says “Web job Running”!

Any ideas about this behaviour and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a setting in the Configure tab called “ALWAYS ON“ which it has a very bold message on top of it that says “Should be turned on if you have a job that runs continuously”.

Here is how this setting looks like:
[image]

I also have a blog post about this issue:

https://koukia.ca/microsoft-windows-azure-webjobs-and-how-to-keep-them-awake-16283c28f19f#.nentaowwo